# Selecting vertices bu U or V loops with python?

Tags: python, uv, vertices, select, loop

Thanks to the help I got here, I am now very near to achieving my goal namely storing information about the vertices so that I can select them according to their U (from 0 to 1000) and V (from 0 to 1000) indices (and not coordinates).

I want to know if there is, in Blender 3.12 Python, a built in way to select a loop (u or v) when one vertex is selected (equivalent to ALT + click) or how to use the Select_Next() , Select_Previous() and Select_I_Forgot_what(start, number, offset), which would solve my problem in one go. The thing is they seem to work on the vertex’s Index and not with the UV loops. Or, in the worst scenario, I want to use the Select_More() operator at vertex level. Has anyone a working example of a script using this? The more basic the better.

Comment: A better question. A vertex being already selected. 

What I want is a “select_more_uv(u, v, off_u, off_v, full_u, full_v)” operator. This should be working at EDIT level on the vertices, not in the UV map. 

u is the number of vertices we want to add on the u direction, v the number of vertices on the v direction, off_u the offset for the start in u direction, off_v the same on the v direction, full_u(or v) 2 booleans if we want to select the whole row. 

It should return a selection that we can use and easily change in the Geometry Nodes like a color_layer. 

How can I build it?